# liblapack.so.3gf not found

Tags: 16.04, r

I need to run some analyses in R 2.14 (this old version is needed to run an old package). I'm using 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I need the quantreg packag in R. But this gives me some error: liblapack.so.3gf and libblas.so.3gf are not found.

```
> lien@lien:~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/quantreg/libs$ ll
drwxr-xr-x  2 lien lien   4096 déc.  12 11:45 ./
drwxr-xr-x 10 lien lien   4096 oct.  16  2012 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 lien lien      0 déc.  12 11:45 export
-rw-r--r--  1 lien lien 254176 déc.   8 16:51 libblas.so.3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     31 déc.  12 09:43 liblapack.so.3gf -> /usr/lib/R/lib/liblapack.so.3gf
lien@lien:~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/quantreg/libs$ ldd quantreg.so
```

This is the output of the "ldd quantreg.so"
 - linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff435fc000) 
 - liblapack.so.3gf => not found 
 - libblas.so.3gf => not found 
 - libgfortran.so.3 =>    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f3a65cf9000)

- libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3a659f0000)
- libR.so => /usr/lib/libR.so (0x00007f3a6543e000)
- libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3a65074000)
- libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0  (0x00007f3a64e35000)
- libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
  (0x00007f3a64c1f000)
- lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055780a4b9000)
- libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0x00007f3a649e0000)
- libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6
  (0x00007f3a6479a000)
- libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f3a6452a000)
- liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f3a64307000)
- libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0   (0x00007f3a640f7000)
- libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f3a63edd000)
- librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f3a63cd4000)
- libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3a63ad0000)
- libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f3a638ae000)
- libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
  (0x00007f3a63690000)
- libatlas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libatlas.so.3 (0x00007f3a630f2000)
- libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f3a62ec8000)

However, both packages libblas and liblapack are installed:

```
> lien@lien:~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/quantreg/libs$ dpkg -l | grep 'openblas\|atlas\|lapack' 
ii  libatlas3-base   3.10.2-9         amd64      Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, generic shared 
ii  liblapack3       3.6.0-2ubuntu2   amd64      Library of linear algebra routines 3 - shared version
```

I already tried making a lync for liblapack.so.3gf but this also doesn't work. 
I don't have a lot of experience with Ubuntu, and don't really know what else I can try.

Comment: I realized now that I was running the package before on Linux 14.04 and that worked like a charm. Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 the problems started. 
Are there special requirements to run libblapack and libblas in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu 16.04 installing the packages `liblapack3` and `libblas3` should fix your issue.