# Ubuntu 18.04 liblapack.so.3gf not found

Tags: 18.04

I am trying to use the old photogrammetry software Phython Photogrammetry Toolbox. However, during the PMVS step I get an error message in the terminal saying that the program cannot find the library liblapack.so.3gf. I got some other missing libraries which I could successfully solve by installing the corresponding packages.

liblapack3 and libblas3 are installed (as suggesting in this similar case: [liblapack.so.3gf not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860947/liblapack-so-3gf-not-found)). They, however, do not seem to include the liblapack.so.3gf anymore as I could not locate the file anywhere and I still get the error message.

Comment: The only place that I could find `liblapack.so.3gf` is : "revolution-mkl" from multiverse category.

Comment: @ Ravexina Thx. I installed the package and it installed the library into /usr/lib/R/lib/. Unfortunately, I still get the same error: liblapack.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. I followed this instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s#21173918 but I still get the same error message :(

Comment: Seems I made a spelling mistake while exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The library is now found.

Comment: So it has been solved? if so I post it as an answer ...

Comment: Yes it is solved. The program runs now (after adding some more libraries).

Answer (score 0):

The only place that I could find `liblapack.so.3gf` is "revolution-mkl" package from multiverse category.

Make sure multiverse repository is enabled then install it:

```
sudo apt install revolution-mkl
```

To enable multiverse (if it's not): [How do I enable the "multiverse" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository)